# error in saving Array of array of objects to the mongo DB using flask

Tags: arrays, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I'm trying to save the object having the array of array of objects in one field using flask by pymongo but what happening is that is saved as array of object instead.

here is my object

```
{
  "_id":ObjectId("62e365c6f1cb5816b7a152f8"),
  "_class": "org.data.model",
  "topic" : "Demo",
  "extra" : {
              "type":"periodic",
              "sessions":[
                           [ { "morning":"8:00"},{ "noon":"1:00" },{"evening":"5:00"}],
                           [ { "morning":"10:00"},{"noon":"3:00" },{"evening":"7:00"}],
                           [ { "morning":"9:00"},{"noon":"2:00"},{"evening":"6:00"}]
                         ],
              "mentor":"Dr Vishual Raj",
            }
}
```

the data is sent as mentioned above to the pymongo to update

but the data is saved to mongo as mentioned below

```
{
  "_id":ObjectId("62e365c6f1cb5816b7a152f8"),
  "_class": "org.data.model",
  "topic" : "Demo",
  "extra" : {
              "type":"periodic",
              "sessions": [ { "morning":"9:00"}],{ "noon":"2:00"},{"evening":"6:00"}]
              "mentor":"Dr Vishual Raj",
            }
}
```

the sessions field is not correctly updated but other fields are updated correctly.

here is my python code

```
document={
  "_id":ObjectId("62e365c6f1cb5816b7a152f8"),
  "_class": "org.data.model",
  "topic" : "Demo",
  "extra" : {
              "type":"periodic",
              "sessions":[
                           [ { "morning":"8:00"},{ "noon":"1:00" },{"evening":"5:00"}],
                           [ { "morning":"10:00"},{"noon":"3:00" },{"evening":"7:00"}],
                           [ { "morning":"9:00"},{"noon":"2:00"},{"evening":"6:00"}]
                         ],
              "mentor":"Dr Vishual Raj",
            }
}
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient(getConfig('MONGO')['MONGO_CONN_STRING'])
mydb = myclient[getConfig('MONGO')['MONGO_DB']]
my_collection = mydb["collection_data"]
x = my_collection.update_one({"_id": ObjectId("62e365c6f1cb5816b7a152f8")},{ "$set": document})
```

i want to save the whole object only please suggest me how to update the data as it is been sent to pymongo to mongo db

Comment: Please share a [mre].

Comment: Sure kiner, i have edited it